# Multiple ASP.NET MVC code-first sites using the same DB/Auth/Model/backend - how?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, repository-pattern

So I may have a bit of a strange situation here, and I need some guidance.

The company I work for has a number of small sites, with each site selling a different custom program. The sites are badly in need of an entire rewrite from top to bottom, and my boss has agreed that a login and online purchase/registration is required. This means user accounts, the ability to download a trial from within the user account, the ability to register that trial also from within the user account and the ability to view a list of previous purchases/registrations and product keys.

The thing is, I want a sign-on from one site to be usable on another. Plus, all of this will need to be administered (on our end) from one admin interface. So my thought is that this will all have to be driven by a single database.

Just to be clear: the front-end for each site needs to be different - sometimes only subtly, but in some cases by quite a bit (marketing differences). The backend (both Admin as well as for the Client interface), is identical in structure regardless of the site URL, but the Client interface needs to show different content (programs to download, lists of computers where the program has been registered on, etc.) depending on what URL is being used.

My problem is that I am not entirely sure how to do this from a code-first perspective. The sites are small, quite easy to build on their own, but I want them all within the same Solution so that a change to the model will be reflected across all of them (I will be able to see where things go sideways if the model gets altered - Intellisense is my friend!).

I have looked into Areas, but Areas seem to be a way of partitioning off gross differences *within* a site (things like resource files - JavaScript, CSS, etc. - remain in the root, whereas in my case each site will need different resource files). I need each section to be its own unique site, with its own unique URL. When this gets pushed to the server, I need each site to be “independent” in that they *can* sit in entirely different accounts on the same Windows Plesk server (Plesk was not my choice, but the company has clients that need a control panel interface to their own accounts). The only **strong** commonality between any of them is the database that they will make use of -- in fact, all of them will be making use of the same tables, with very few differences between the sites.

My other problem is that I do not know how to properly implement having multiple projects within a single solution, and all projects making use of the same model that is implemented/constructed only once. I have not yet made the jump to Repository Patterns, so I am completely in the dark with respect to that functionality.

If anyone has a suggestion, I would love to hear about it.

Comment: This question is better suited for [Programmers SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you just need to create a class library where you will put your entities and context. If you're using Identity, you'll also put all the Identity-related entity classes here. You'll enable migrations on this class library. The other projects in your solution, then, will have a reference to this class library. You'll need to add the connection string to the individual projects' Web.config files, but other than that, everything will just work.

This is enough to ensure that all the projects are working from a common database and user store. However, in order to actually share authentication, such that signing into one, signs you into all them, you'll have to take one of two paths, depending on how they will be deployed.

1. If all of the sites will be on the same domain (different subdomains are fine). Then all you need to do is generate a machine key and ensure that each site uses the same machine key in its Web.config. The auth cookie will be added on the wildcard domain, and any subdomain of that domain will be able to see it. Sharing the machine key is to ensure that they can each decrypt it what any one them sets as the auth cookie.
2. If not all the sites will be on the same domain, then you're in for some pain. You'll have to set up a SSO system, which is non-trivial and far beyond the scope of Stack Overflow to help you with. There's entire companies devoted just to building SSO systems for organizations.

Comment: It is *highly unlikely* that any client will be making use of more than one type of software. The programs are all vastly different, and for widely different industries, so it is likely that a client will need to access only one client interface -- being able to log into all of them at once is not required. However, if they do have a login for one, they *can* log into any of them. They just would have zero content for the others, because they never actually downloaded and bought any other products.